# How to increase number of spinner by user key in value

Tags: c#, android-fragments, xamarin.android, spinner, android-spinner

How to add number of spinner by user fill in in category line ?

here is my code in fragment.
please help me.

```
 public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Category1, container, false);
        txtCat1Name = (EditText)rootView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtCat1Name);
        txtCat1Length = (EditText)rootView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtCat1Length);
        txtCat1Line = (EditText)rootView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtCat1Line);
        btnSaveCat1 = (Button)rootView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnSaveCat1);

        noOfLine = Int16.Parse(txtCat1Line.Text);
        btnSaveCat1.Click += btnSaveCat1_click;
        txtCat1Line.KeyPress += txtCat1Line_KeyPress;


        return rootView;
    }

 private void txtCat1Line_KeyPress(object sender, View.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var spinners = new Spinner[0];
        if (e.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Up && txtCat1Line.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < noOfLine; i++)
            {
                var spinner = new Spinner(this.Activity);

                spinners[i] = spinner;
            }

        }
}
```

how to add spinner by user key in in category line.
[image]

Comment: Do you mean adding multiple Spinner controls dynamically

Comment: yeah...which mean..if user input 2..will loop 2 spinner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a root layout for the Xaml of the rootView with an id :

e.g your `Layout.Category1`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id = "@+id/root_layout"
>
   ....
</LinearLayout>
```

then in the fragment :

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Category1, container, false);
    txtCat1Name = (EditText)rootView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtCat1Name);
    txtCat1Length = (EditText)rootView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtCat1Length);
    txtCat1Line = (EditText)rootView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtCat1Line);
    btnSaveCat1 = (Button)rootView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnSaveCat1);
    rootLayout = rootView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.root_layout);
    btnSaveCat1.Click += btnSaveCat1_click;
    txtCat1Line.KeyPress += txtCat1Line_KeyPress;


    return rootView;
}


private void txtCat1Line_KeyPress(object sender, View.KeyEventArgs e)
    {


        e.Handled = false;
        if (TextUtils.IsEmpty(txtCat1Line .Text))
        {
            return;
        }
        noOfLine = Int16.Parse(txtCat1Line .Text);
        if (e.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Down && e.KeyCode == Keycode.Enter)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < noOfLine; i++)
            {
                var spinner = new Spinner(this.Activity);
                layout.AddView(spinner);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

the EditText xaml：

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id = "@+id/txtCat1Line"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    android:inputType="number"
/>
```

The answer code basically provides a dynamic add Spinner method,
and here I recommend not listening on the KeyPress event(Maybe you could add a button to trigger or listen for focus and so on).

Comment: when i debug until rootLayout.AddView(spinner);
get error already..lol

Comment: I worked normally during the test. What error did you report

Comment: where i should declare the spinner item ya ?

Comment: you could under " var spinner = new Spinner(this.Activity);" could you show me your error message

Comment: how about..define id to each spinner ?

Comment: look like keypress not workable..how to use lose fucus ?

Comment: You are dynamically adding a Spinner,normally, instead of setting the id, you get the Spinner object you want.You can use "spinner.Id = View.GenerateViewId()" if you want to set it up .If you use keypress, you can set "android:imeOptions="actionGo".

Comment: for listening in action "e.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Down && e.KeyCode == Keycode.Enter ",the last call "e.Handled = true"

Comment: If it helps you, please give me a mark. Thank you very much

Comment: @LeoZhu...i put "e.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Down && e.KeyCode == Keycode.Enter " and "e.Handled = true" also set action go..there are no response when i fill in the line number

Comment: you should press the enter key on the keyboard

Comment: same..no response too

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/edit-text you could

Comment: you could refer to the link

Comment: but keypress did not generate the spinner

Comment: i would check it for you when i go back to work the day after tomorrow. I am on vacation these two days，so you

Comment: so you could temporarily follow the orginal monitoring method

Comment: now..i am doing table layout..how do i add my db data to a dynamic table layout ?
do you have any sample ?

Comment: Xamarin forms or xamarin Android ?

Comment: Xamarin Android.

Comment: could you describe it in more detail ?

Comment: ..hi friend can i ask you some question ?
i have a adapter for a list view..inside have radio button..now all radio button can checked..how to control only 1 radio button can checked ?

Comment: You could create a collection to store the check status of the radiobutton, and then load the collection when it is loaded in “getView”. You could create a new question, and I will paste some sample code to you

Comment: my new question on this page.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54211937/how-to-get-checked-radio-button-and-how-to-control-only-one-radio-button-selecte